# iOS 7 beta install says "device not registered as part of the dev program"

Tags: iphone-developer-program, ios7

I just downloaded and attempted to install the iOS 7 beta, but when I try to activate the device, I'm getting an error:

> We’re unable to complete your activation. This device is not registered as part of the iPhone Developer Program. If you are a member of the Program, please register your device in the iPhone Developer Program Portal.

However, I am registered. Here's a screenshot of my devices page: [image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: all I did was download the ipsw file from the developer site, and install it in Xcode. Then I used iTunes to activate it... Maybe try that?

Comment: I can't. I get the same error in iTunes. http://i.imgur.com/IEtssN4.png

Comment: Aren't iOS betas under NDA? (I'm also not sure what the policy is on asking questions if it is, but I imagine it could "bring heat" on SO if Apple has a problem with any content on it: I'm sure [meta] has material on this issue.)

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I might be spreading FUD. The question isn't about any specific functionality in the beta so even if it was the NDA probably wouldn't apply. (Obviously, IANAL, so everything is possible.)

Comment: Having the same issue too and I did restore like 10 times now :S

Comment: There is a whole forum for this on the dev site.

Comment: Have a guess. I'll give you a hint. The logo is on the back of the device.

Comment: It appears that the support site is down, at least for me. Thats why I was curious.

Comment: The [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com) are the place for you to go seek help for this.

Comment: Did you just register your device today?

Comment: @millimoose: Meta does indeed have material: [Limits of iOS 6 NDA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137726/limits-of-ios-6-nda) and related questions. It is not SO's policy, responsibility, or concern to enforce or police NDAs between other parties. Ideally, therefore, none of us users should worry about it either.

Comment: To the mods that closed this, it says "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development", and the installation of iOS7 today is something that we need in order to develop for iOS7 when it's released this fall. That's why I posted this here.

Comment: No moderator was involved here (in fact, I left this alone to see what the community decided), but I don't know that Stack Overflow is the best place to have discussions about NDA-covered beta releases of software. The information here probably won't be relevant or useful past the next couple of weeks, as the beta evolves, so I can see how people might feel this was too localized in time. The question was also devolving into noise, and I had to delete a lot of non-answers and comments.

Comment: @Josh That was hardly my point. Thing is, discussing specifics of a beta here *might* be in violation of the NDA you agreed to. And asking a question about it is inviting other users to do the same. What the meta question seems to say is that there's no reason for SO moderators or the community to get involved in this *as a third party*. That doesn't mean the people asking and answering shouldn't keep this concern in mind.

Comment: @BradLarson, got it. Thanks for the explanation. And I agree, most of the replies were noise, and I think as of next week this post will be worthless, it's only good for the next few days.

Comment: You're right, @millimoose, a person who has signed an NDA should keep that in mind; your comment above says something about Apple applying legal pressure to SO.

Comment: @Josh What I had in mind is asking for said content to be removed etc. Not being a threat to SO, rather a pain in the ass. Not being a lawyer I don't know if they would or would not be in their right, just that *if* they were, *then* it would be a valid policy choice to ban questions that cause this, *thus* [meta] should be checked w/r/t said policy choice. I never meant to say "you shouldn't post stuff that makes Apple angry". (I admit this sounds overly cautious. But then again, Apple likes their secrecy and their legal department as well.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This solution is working for many people (including myself).

1. Make sure you actually do add your device [I actually hadn't] (log into apple developers -> members center -> certificates, identifiers, and profiles -> devices -> + button)
2. Download an old version of iOS (I used this link: http://www.mashinglab.com/download-ios-6-1-4-ipsw-file-for-iphone-5-ipad-ipod-touch-direct-links/)
3. Put your phone into DFU Mode (http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode)
4. In iTunes, hold down the option button and click restore, and browse for the file you downloaded in step 2.
5. Wait for it to restore to older version.
6. In iTunes, hold down the option button and click **update** (not restore!), and browse for the file you downloaded from the apple developer page for iOS 7.

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't work because the developer registration server is under such a heavy load. If you had this problem because you did a restore to iOS 7 then here is a workaround I can confirm works.

1. Enter DFU mode
2. Downgrade to 6.1.3
3. In [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) choose "Use for development"
4. Deploy and run an application
5. Backup in iTunes
6. Upgrade to iOS 7 beta 1

This works, because it locally enables the device as a development device so when it upgrades it already knows it is a developer device and doesn't need to check the developer center activation server.

Comment: I tried solutions found on the Apple Dev Forums with no luck. So I'm hoping you're right. I'll keep trying through the night and post here if I get it to work.

Comment: I have the same issue too. I'll try to downgrade to iOS 6.1.3 if possible and see if this works. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a whole bunch of confirmed solutions in the forum post *[Unable to complete activation - account not registered](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5094054)*.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of trying this. I'll report back once I fail or succeed.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to summarize the linked material here. Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Comment: I'm letting this stay for now, despite it being flagged by multiple people, because the only place you're going to find definitive answers to material about the beta is at Apple's forums. Please go there instead of dumping "me too" responses all over this question.

Comment: I tried what is suggested in these posts, which is to restart the device in DFU mode, restore back to iOS6, restore the backup and the try to install iOS7 again. It did not work for me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Additionally it is against the NDA to post information inside that link to this forum for the time being.

Comment: @borrrden: The link in this answer goes to a public forum, not the dev forums.

Comment: @JoshCaswell So it does, my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue!

1. Restore back to iOS 6.1.4 first if you are stuck on iOS 7 activation screen
2. When you are on iOS 6.1.4 now you just plug your iPhone to your Mac/PC and open up the iTunes
3. Hold down the Shift key if you are on PC or if you are on Mac hold down Option key and press on "UPDATE" not "Restore"

And now you just wait and your phone will be activated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did that worked perfectly

Boot to DFU mode, and restore 6.1.4
Restore icloud backup
Load Xcode, click use for development
open itunes, option click **upgrade**
select ios7

It boots right up to latest icloud backup, and starts restoring apps.

Comment: I'm going for this route too and hope all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a restore again through Xcode. Once restarted, it worked again. Maybe do another restore through [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) with the downloaded dmg?